# Move a little image over the screen

Tags: android, animation

I would like to know how I can move a small image on the screen. The user clicks for instance  a small block and after that I would like to slide it over the screen.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create a TranslationAnimation and apply it.  Should look something like this:

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        view.startAnimation(slide);
    }
});
```

Here is a link to the info on [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html)